# Better class organization for my C# project

Tags: c#, class, code-organization

I'm trying to organize my functions and classes in better way. Currently I have following primary classes (Note: all these classes have lots of properties and functions, but for sake of clarification I wash them all away):

```
internal class Class0{ } 

internal class Class1: Class0 { }

internal class Class2: Class1 
{ 
    List<Class1> mainDataStructure; 
}
```

I'm quite OK with organization of above mentioned classes, but my main concern are following classes.

```
public class Class3: Class2
{
    InsertClass anInstance = new InsertClass();

    public void Insert(Item item)
    {
        anInstance.mainDataStructure = mainDataStructure;
        anInstance.Insert(item);
    }
}

internal class InsertClass
{
    List<Class1> mainDataStructure;

    internal void Insert(Item item)
    {
        // adds item to mainDataStructure.

        // some clean-ups using following function
        // how to clean-up ? User will define it.
        CleanUp();
    }

    // a function that use should implement
    // define it as:
    internal abstract string CleanUp();
    // or as:
    internal Func<string> CleanUp();
}
```

So as you noticed, my problem arises when I'm trying to define some classes (e.g., `Class4`) that manipulate my `mainDataStructure`. What I can do (as I did here) is to pass the `mainDataStructure` to the classes that will manipulate it. Although it works, but for me it does not seem elegant. I'm wondering if there is any possibility of re-organizing my `Class3` and `Class4` in a better way.

Besides, the classes that manipulate `mainDataStructure` (e.g., `Class4`) has some functions that should be defined by end-user ... which I'm totally stuck there! If I define the function as `abstract` the user must inherit the class and define the `abstract` function in the child class, or if I define them with delegates `Func<>` the user must pass the function definition. The main concern with these solutions are the accessibility level of the class! I'm highly recemended to have only `Class3` as public. Therefore, inheritance is out of question, and for delegate, there should be a way in new organization to pass the function definition to `Class4` from within `Class3`.

I appreciate any help for this project organization.

**Class Explanation**
This project is an Information Retrieval project. `mainDataStructure` stores the information. 
`Class3` is kinda user interface. The user begins interaction by getting an instance of this class; and does everything by that instance (e.g., add new information, retrievals, statistics, and etc.). 
`Class4` adds new information to `mainDataStructure`. 
`Class5` retrieves the some kind of similarity between stored information. 
`Class6` gets some statistics of `mainDataStructure` (e.g., right-tailed probability)
and so on so forth.

*Example: add a new information item* 
Use the instance of `Class3` and call the `public void Add(Item item)`. This method will then use the instance of `Class4` and it's `internal void Add(Item item)` method to take care of all new item insertion process. See modified above code

Comment: Your example code does not help me to understand your problem, I don't quite get what you're trying to accomplish. You're not passing the datastructure as far as I can see. It seems you're setting a property then calling into a function that does something?
Try to read about Dependency Injection, Inversion of Control and Pure Functions/ Separation of Concern.

Comment: This is a bit open for opinion I think, but your question isn't too clear. Two things that come to mind are interfaces instead of abstraction, and some dependency injection, so you can pass what you want into the classes.

Comment: Examples in code organization and design patterns are almost never in terms of ABC XYZ foobar, but in terms of things like car, bicycle, employee, customer, from my experience in a comp sci course.

Comment: It seems like you try to solve everything with inheritance. Having 4-5 levels of inheritance creates coupled and hard to follow code. Create independent methods which work on the entire class instead. (i.e. `ManipulateDataStructure(class3, arg1, arg2)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) combined with e.g. a [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

```
public interface MainDataStructureManipulations {
   // define all needed functions here.
}

public abstract class Class3 {
    static Class3 getInstanceWith(MainDataStructureManipulations strategy) {
        return new Class4(strategy);
    }

    private Class3() {}
}

internal class Class4 : Class3 {
    MainDataStructureManipulations strategy;
    public Class4(MainDataStructureManipulations strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
}
```

You might not even need an additional `Class4` if all your strategy requirements are covered with `MainDataStructureManipulations`.

---

A Factory is a method that creates an object instance for you. The great thing is you don't have to know exactly of which class this instance is, as long as it implements the base class the factory specified. In this case above, you do not have to expose `Class4`, and the user of the library will never see it, either, but can interact with the instance just like with any instance of a class that is derived from `Class3`.

A Strategy encapsulates functionality with simple methods. I chose it because it seemed to fit quite well to your description, but I might have been wrong. A strategy just holds the methods for interaction, if you want to store state maybe another pattern would be more appropriate. If you tell us what you are really trying to do we can give more detailed advice.

Comment: Your suggestion seems interesting; however, it's not so clear to me, maybe because I'm unfamiliar with Factory and Strategy. Would you mind please clarify ?